Having a problem retrieving data from Spoonacular API
soo im trying to retrieve some data for food items that can be purchased in my app. Ive called the API and i have connected it to my Isar database for local storage but it is not displaying the items from the API after i added the price feature. Here is my API service file
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../model/food_item.dart';

class ApiService {
  final String apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY';
  final String apiUrl = 'https://api.spoonacular.com/food/products/search';

  Future<List<FoodItem>> fetchFoodItems({int number = 10}) async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('$apiUrl?apiKey=$apiKey'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      final List<dynamic> products = data['products'];

      return products.map((product) {
        return FoodItem(
          id: product['id'],
          title: product['title'],
          image: product['image'],
          price: (product['price'] as num?)?.toDouble() ?? 0.0,
        );
      }).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load food items');
    }
  }
}

And here is my food_item.dart file
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

part 'food_item.freezed.dart';
part 'food_item.g.dart';

@freezed
class FoodItem with _$FoodItem {
  @JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
  const factory FoodItem({
    required int id,
    required String title,
    required String image,
    required double price,
  }) = _FoodItem;

  factory FoodItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$FoodItemFromJson(json);
}

@collection
class FoodItemSchema {
  Id? id;

  late String title;
  late String image;
  late double price;

  FoodItemSchema();

  factory FoodItemSchema.fromFoodItem(FoodItem item) {
    return FoodItemSchema()
      ..id = item.id
      ..title = item.title
      ..image = item.image
      ..price = item.price;

  }

  FoodItem toFoodItem() {
    return FoodItem(
      id: id!,
      title: title,
      image: image,
      price: price,
    );
  }
}


And finally my food_Store.dart file
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';
import '../model/food_item.dart';
import '../service/api_service.dart';
import '../service/isar_service.dart';

part 'food_store.g.dart';

class FoodStore = _FoodStore with _$FoodStore;

abstract class _FoodStore with Store {
  final IsarService isarService = IsarService();
  final ApiService apiService = ApiService();

  @observable
  ObservableList<FoodItem> foodItems = ObservableList<FoodItem>();

  @observable
  ObservableList<FoodItem> shoppingBasket = ObservableList<FoodItem>();

  @action
  Future<void> loadFoodItems() async {
    final isar = await isarService.db;
    final itemsFromDb = await isar.foodItemSchemas.where().findAll();

    if (itemsFromDb.isEmpty) {
      try {
        final itemsFromApi = await apiService.fetchFoodItems();
        foodItems.addAll(itemsFromApi);
        await isarService.saveFoodItems(itemsFromApi);
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error fetching food items: $e');
      }
    } else {
      foodItems.addAll(itemsFromDb.map((item) => item.toFoodItem()).toList());
    }
  }

  @action
  void addToBasket(FoodItem item) {
    shoppingBasket.add(item);
  }

  @action
  Future<void> checkout() async {
    // Perform checkout logic here (e.g., POST request)
    shoppingBasket.clear();
  }
}


I think the thing causing it is within these three files.Your help will be much appreciated
I checked my API limits and found out they were still available so i ruled that out, i tried using build_runner to rebuild the code and it worked with no errors after adding the price. I went through the API service file but could still not find any errors from my point of view
